# Can any graph be represented by a formula?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I am only in high school but interested in maths. Can any graph be represented by a formula or does the graph have to have certain characteristics like a pattern etc?

Comment: Hi @SRawes, given what you most likely meant by your question, graph theory is not the correct tag here. I understand why it was a natural choice though, I remember before I knew what graph theory was I also assumed it was the study of 'graphs' like I had learned about in pre-calculus. Your question would probably land more in what is known as complexity theory.

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking whether a function has to be given by some sort of algorithm or logic, then the answer is no: A function $f:X \to Y$ is simply a subset of $S_f \subset X\times Y$ such that for each $x\in X$, there exists exactly one point $(x, y)\in S_f$; the point $y$ is denoted by $f(x)$. Note that this assignment is deterministic (though not necessarily computable by a human, algorithm, etc.).

We can talk about the kinds of functions you describe, though; they're just a smaller subset of the space of all functions. For that, "computable function" is probably the concept you want. If you want to relax the deterministic requirement, then "random variable" is probably what you're looking for, but note that there are quite a few technical details required to define them properly.

Comment: Yes. That $S_f$ is the graph in question. Therefore, your answer is actually a yes.

Comment: If the OP is asking whether an arbitrary curve in the plane is the graph of a function, then the answer is clearly no.

Comment: OP would understand 0% of this answer

Comment: Then the OP can ask for a clarification or look up the terms involved.

Comment: That's not very helpful for a high school student asking a simple question

Comment: So basically a function is just matching one list of values to another list of values. Many times these functions don't have a pattern or a fixed algorithm to match the values between the lists.